# function having a ip-range string as argument and returning array containing list of ips in 'C'

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I am 2 month old kid with using C. I have a simple problem with passing ip-range as argument to main function and getting an array with indivisual ips.

eg. func-ip-range should take 1.1.1.1-10 as argv and return an array [1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3 ......... 1.1.1.10].

The way I was approaching this problem is as follows and I could not get the "segmentation fault" debugged as I have no Idea where the code is choking.

Any help would be very much appreciated to save this kid.

Approach is to pass the command line argument to *ip_str and read this string char by char. Once I meet first '.' I increase the count 'c' and when count c == 3 i want to store the string from there to a new string variable till I reach '-' and after reaching '-' the rest of the string to a new string. But I have serious issue with my exposure to the programme writing and debugging.

The direction on how to reach the problem other than this will be very good for my learning.

```
    void array_ip(char *ip_str,char **iplist)
    {
    for(i=0,j=0;*(ip_str+i) != '\0';i++)
    {
            if(*(ip_str+i)=='.')
            {c++;
            }
            if(c==3 && (*(ip_str+i )!= '-'))
            {
            *(a+j) = *(ip_str+i);
            j++;
            }
            if(*(ip_str+i) == '-')
            {
            break;
            }
    }
    for(k=0;*(ip_str+i) != '\0';k++,i++)
    {
    *(b+k)=*(ip_str+i);
    }

    printf("the starting last octet is %s \n",a);
    printf("the Ending last octet is %s \n",b);
    }
```

Comment: Where/how are `a`, `b`, `c` declared?

Comment: Note: your ` *(b+k)=*(ip_str+i);` is equivalent to ` b[k] = ip_str[i];` , which is more readable for humans. BTW: is `b` supposed to be an array or pointer ?

Comment: @wildplasser .... Thank you sir for the point. I will take care of human readability in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the help of  ?[strrchr()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

Do a man 3 strrchr on your linux if you are using linux

**Edit** : Use `strtok` instead :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        char str[] = "1.1.1.1-10";
        char * temp;

        temp = strtok(str,"-");
        temp = strtok(NULL,"-");
        int number = atoi(temp);
        printf("%d",number);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another function you could instead use is [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) using "-" as delimiter. Once you have your two strings, you know till what limit you have to provide output of ips.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to get started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int a, b, c, d, len;

   if(argc != 2)
     exit(1);

   if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d.%d.%d.%d-%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &len) == 5)
   {
     pintf("Got IP range\n");
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you to take out some time and guiding me. It was really helpful as i learnt a lot of new things through your inputs. I am just pasting code which I wrote to get prefix (11.1.1.) and startValue (251) - endValue (254). Which I will concatenate using strcat and pass results to an array. I am still not very comfortable in passing pointer arguments to function and get arrays from pointers but very soon I will be.

Thanks Again !!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char str[]="11.1.1.251-254";
char *temp, *a,*b,*c,*temp2,*q;
char prefix[50];
int i,count,k;
temp = strrchr(str,'.');
if(temp!=NULL)
{
printf("found a '.' as %s\n",temp);
}

b = strtok(temp,"-");
c = strtok(NULL,"-");       
b = strtok(b,".");

for(i=0,k=0,count=0;count<3;i++,k++)
{

prefix[k]=str[i];
if(str[i]=='.')
{
count++;
}
}
printf("%s \n",prefix);
printf("%s \n",b);
printf("%s \n",c);
return 0;
}
```